# How create facebook like button for one posts?

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

I want create like button for one facebook post, and including this button in my site.

For test I use this form developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button and this URL to post www.facebook.com/155730127901365/posts/1138450862962615.

But this creating button I cant like and box count don’t show like for this post [here is youtube video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p4Fkx2cFr4A)

Also I tried embedded this post in my site, but I too cant like this post. 
[here is youtube video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yu-IhkHb_yM)

Can you help me? Its bug? How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Buttons can be used for Facebook Pages and external Websites, but not for single Facebook Posts.

Embedded Posts are for single Facebook Posts, and the Like Button does not work for those.

Comment: what about embedded post? why i can't like him?

Comment: As i said, you can only like Facebook Pages and external Website Links. Embedded Posts are for single Facebook Posts, and you can´t use the Like Button for that. i will add it to the answer for clarification.

Comment: that is really all there is to know. it just works for pages and external websites. that´s it.